# ActualHeight and ActualWidth in Webview

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp

I'm creating a webview in c# code in UWP application. I have attached a LoadCompleted event to it. When this event gets trigger ActaulHeight And ActualWidth is 0. I tried to set its MinWidth and MinHeight to 500. But its is not working.

I did the same thing by creating a webview control in XAML but in that case ActualHeight and ActualWidth is 500.

Here is the code :

```
 public WebView _webView { get; set; }

 public ViewPage()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
     _webView = new WebView
        {
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            Source = new Uri(@"https://www.google.com"),
            MinHeight = 500,
            MinWidth = 500
        };
}

  private void _webView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
       // Here, when  I debug _webview ActualHeight and ActaulWidth is zero.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` reflect the size of the UI element in the layout. In the C# code you only created an instance of `WebView` class, but didn't really place it anywhere on the page, hence these values were zero.

On the contrary, when you used XAML, not only you created an instance of `WebView` class, but also embedded this UI element into the page that was displayed when you ran the app, so `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` contained actual dimensions of the UI element on that page.